# Can I disperse a droplet with electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, water

If I have a droplet of water, can I apply an electromagnetic field in order to disperse the droplet into smaller subdroplets (tiny vapor) and fill a space with them? The same way that magnetic dust spreads across a space under a magnetic field. But the electromagnetic field should be able to break the intermolecular forces that form a droplet. Is that possible? What kind of magnitude are we talking about? More or less under an electromagnetical field (what else?) to burst a droplet into tiny droplets.

Comment: This paper, Breakup of fluid droplets in electric and magnetic fields, may help.  However, it seems to be a study of fluid drops contained in other fluids: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/jds60/jfm188133electricdrops.pdf